# Passing the key to the search form does not work

Tags: php, symfony

Currently, I am updating the system running on the existing Symfony 2.3 (currently 3.0.9), and I am verifying the operation.
Symfony isn't working well on a page that lists a search form and brand.
When you select a brand in the list, the key is passed to the url, the selected brand and days is entered in the search form, and the search is sorted.
However, although the key is passed to the url, the search form is not filled in and the search sort is not performed.
Do you have any advice?

**Code**
PostController

```
<?php

namespace Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\Hq;

use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\BaseController;
use Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Post\PostSearchType;
use Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Util\Pagination;

/**
 * Access analysis controller
 *
 * @Route("/hq/post")
 */
class PostController extends BaseController
{
    // TODO New screen
    /**
     * @Route("/", defaults={"_format"="html"}, requirements={"_format"="html|csv"})
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_HQ_MANAGE")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $perPage = 10;

        // Create a search form
        $searchForm = $this->createForm(PostSearchType::class, null, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('ahi_sp_admin_hq_post_index'),
        ));

        // Get search criteria
        $params = $this->getSearchParameter($searchForm, $request);

        $pagination = null;
        $no = 0;
        if ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'html') {
            // When outputting html
             // Create pagenation
            $count = $this->get('admin.postService')->countPostBySearchParams(
                $params
            );
            $page = $request->query->getInt('page', 1);
            $num = $request->query->getInt('num', $perPage);
            $pagination = new Pagination($count, $page, $num, 10);
            // No. calculation
            $no = ($perPage*$page) - $perPage;
        } elseif ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'csv') {
            // When outputting csv
        // Set file name, no pagination
            $request->attributes->set('filename', 'post_article.csv');
        }

        // Get posting status
        $postMetrics = $this->get('admin.postService')->getPostMetrics(
            $params,
            $pagination ? $pagination->getItemsPerPage() : null,
            $pagination ? $pagination->getSelectedPageOffset() : null
        );

        // display
        return array(
            'searchForm' => $searchForm->createView(),
            'postMetrics' => $postMetrics,
            'pagination' => $pagination,
            'no' => $no
        );
    }

}
```

BaseController.php

```
    / **
      * Get search criteria
      *
      * @param Form $searchForm Search form
      * @param Request $request Request
      * @param array $defaultParams Default search criteria
      * @return array Search criteria
      * /
    public function getSearchParameter(Form $searchForm, Request $request, array $defaultParams = array())
     {
         $ submittedData = $request-> query->get($searchForm-> getName());
         $params = $searchForm->submit($submittedData)-> getData();
         return array_merge ($defaultParams, $params);
     }
```

PostService.php

```
<?php
namespace Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Service class regarding posting status
 */
class PostService extends ArticleService
{
    protected $targetArticleType = array('coordinate','recommend','diary','shopevent');
    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        parent::__construct($container);
    }

    /**
     * Get the posting status of each shop
     *
     * @param $params Search conditions
     * @param integer $limit Maximum number of items to be acquired
     * @param integer $offset Offset at acquisition
     * @return Article, totalCount, Coordinate, Recommend, Diary, ShopEvent の配列
     */
    public function getPostMetrics(array $params = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        if (!isset($params['publishDateFrom'])) {
            // Minimum days that can be expressed in unix time
            $params['publishDateFrom'] = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d', 0));
        }

        if (!isset($params['publishDateTo'])) {
            // Today
            $params['publishDateTo'] = new \DateTime('today');
        }
        $params["articleType"] = $this->targetArticleType;
        # Published
        $params["articleStatus"] = 'publish';
        $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder
            ->select(array(
                "a as article",
                "count(a) as totalCount",
                "sum(case when a instance of AhiSpCommonBundle:Coordinate then 1 else 0 end) as Coordinate",
                "sum(case when a instance of AhiSpCommonBundle:Recommend then 1 else 0 end) as Recommend",
                "sum(case when a instance of AhiSpCommonBundle:Diary then 1 else 0 end) as Diary",
                "sum(case when a instance of AhiSpCommonBundle:ShopEvent then 1 else 0 end) as ShopEvent",
            ))
            ->from('AhiSpCommonBundle:Article', 'a')
            ->where('a.publishDateTime between :fromDate and :toDate')
            ->andWhere('a.shop IS NOT NULL')
            ->groupBy('a.shop')
            ->orderBy('totalCount', 'desc');
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('fromDate', $params['publishDateFrom']);
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('toDate', $params['publishDateTo']);
        if ($limit !== null) {
            $queryBuilder->setMaxResults($limit);
        }

        if ($offset !== null) {
            $queryBuilder->setFirstResult($offset);
        }
        $this->entityManager->getRepository('AhiSpCommonBundle:Article')->addSearchParams($queryBuilder, $params);

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

**Version**
Cent OS 6.7 PHP 5.6 Symfony3.0.9

Comment: I don't see anything relevant to your problem in the code snippet. In your controller the form seems to be processed in `$this->getSearchParameter($searchForm, $request);` which is not part of the snippet. In your template there is no form handling. I don't think the code snippet for the form is necessary right now. Please update your snippets accordingly.

Comment: @dbrumann Thank you for your comment. I posted it because I changed the code when I updated it. I changed snippets does it fit your intent?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I still can't see the issue though, but that might be, because I rarely ever use forms with GET. Yan you do a dump() or var_dump() on the result from `getSearchParameter()` and possibly on the request to check if the value is there? My guess is, that the request sends the value, but it is not recognized as part of the form somehow.

Comment: @dbrumann Thank you very much. When I checked $postMetrics with var_dump, the system before running with symfony2.3 was array (1), but the system of symfony3.0 I am testing now shows array (15). Other values seem to be the same. Do you have any idea? $searchForm hasn't changed.

Comment: So `$params` looks the same as in Symfony 2.3 and it has the submitted key in it? If so, please add the code for `getPostMetrics()` and ideally the (relevant) arguments that get passed in.

Comment: @dbrumann Certainly ```$params``` hasn't changed during the update. I added the code for ```getPostMetrics()``` so can you check it?